# Request/Response Cassandra

Tags: haskell, cassandra

I'm working with a Cassandra connector using cql and cql-io libraries, following the API documentation is making me feel dumb, I cannot understand how to make a request to obtain a response.

For now I'm able to connect to the cassandra backend but when I try to make a query using this code

```
selectAllUser :: IO [Identity Text]
selectAllUser = do
                  logger <- Logger.new Logger.defSettings
                  conn <- Client.init logger createConnectionSettings
                  let selectAllQuery = "SELECT * from haskell_cassandra.haskell_users" :: QueryString R () (Identity Text)
                  let queryParam = defQueryParams One ()
                  runClient conn (query selectAllQuery queryParam)
```

I'm receiving this error

```
 internal error: "response body reading: Failed reading: column count: 2 =/= 1\nEmpty call stack\n"
```

I understand with the error, that the response has 2 columns, and that's correct my table has 2 columns. But I dont know how to specify the response row.

Any help or code example it would be great!.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the library and not tried it, but:

Given that `query` has the following signature:

```
query :: (MonadClient m, Tuple a, Tuple b, RunQ q) => q R a b -> QueryParams a -> m [b]
```

Your signature should be (assuming both columns are strings)

```
selectAllUser :: IO [Identity (Text,Text)]
```

Explanation: currently you assign it the type

```
selectAllUser :: IO [Identity Text]
```

which also sets the `b` from `query` to `Text` and therefore it tries to behave as if the row had only a single column.